# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/util/UriTemplateHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm new to Springboot and would like to have a sample project running.

I'm getting the following error upon execution in Intellij:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/util/UriTemplateHandler

**POM is:**

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.2.2.RELEASE
         
    
    com.example
    demo
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    demo
    Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Controller code is:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


public class HelloController {

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public class TestController {
        @RequestMapping (value="map")
        public String getMeSomething()
        {
            return "Got this from Srini!";
        }
    }
}
```

**DemoApplication is:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the **version** of **spring-web** *dependency*

> Each release of Spring Boot provides a curated list of dependencies
>   that it supports. In practice, you do not need to provide a version
>   for any of these dependencies in your build configuration, as Spring
>   Boot manages that for you. When you upgrade Spring Boot itself, these
>   dependencies are upgraded as well in a consistent way.

[See more](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the class UriTemplateHandler is not present in your dependency versión of spring

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

According to https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriTemplateHandler.html, it's present since the version 4.2. Maybe upgrading the versión to 4.2 will solve your problem? (after downloading dependencies ofc).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the spring web dependency to your pom file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```